# EFI Win10 / Linux dual boot setup - cannot select GRUB as the first boot OS

Tags: ubuntu, windows, grub

I am trying to dual-boot Win10 and Linux Mint 21.  Both have been installed, but my computer boots straight into Windows without ever giving a prompt.  If I press F12 during boot, there is only the Windows Bootloader option, no GRUB.  I used SuperGrub2 live USB to boot into the Mint installation.   Once in, ran GRUB install and GRUB update.  Both completed successfully and it detected the windows and Linux partitions.  However, the computer still boots directly to Windows.  I disabled the Windows fast boot option.  I also disabled SecureBoot in the BIOS.  Using UEFI.  Anything else I can check?

Update:
When I run update-grub, I see the following:

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/50_linuxmint.cfg'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-76-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-76-generic
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found Mac OS X on /dev/sdb3
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

**There is no Mac OS X on /dev/sdb3.**  I am using an Acer laptop that never had any Apple OS on it.  It only has Windows and Linux.  Here is the file structure.

fdisk -l shows:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: LITEON CV3-8D256
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F86D106E-8D30-400C-A064-1B8DEEF9D7EB

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda2     206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     239616 265106912 264867297 126.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  499073024 500115455   1042432   509M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  265107456 499073023 233965568 111.6G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
GPT PMBR size mismatch (31955 != 16578559) will be corrected by write.
```

**Not sure what that last line means.  That might also be a clue.**

Under Mint, /dev/sda1 is mapped to /boot/efi.

```
drwx------ 3 root root 1024 Sep  7 22:18 boot
drwx------ 6 root root 1024 Jun 26  2022 EFI
drwx------ 2 root root 1024 Jun 26  2022 System\ Volume\ Information
```

Under boot, there is a grub directory which is empty.

Under EFI, I see

```
drwx------ 2 root root 1024 Jun 26  2022 Boot
drwx------ 4 root root 1024 Jun 26  2022 Microsoft
drwx------ 4 root root 1024 Jun 26  2022 Microsoft.orig
drwx------ 2 root root 1024 Sep  9 12:31 ubuntu
```

Under /boot/efi/EFI/Boot I see:

```
-rwx------ 1 root root 960472 Sep  9 12:49 bootx64.efi
-rwx------ 1 root root  88296 Sep  9 12:49 fbx64.efi
-rwx------ 1 root root 860824 Sep  9 12:49 mmx64.efi
```

Under /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu

I see:

```
-rwx------ 1 root root     108 Sep  9 12:49 BOOTX64.CSV
-rwx------ 1 root root     126 Sep  9 12:49 grub.cfg
-rwx------ 1 root root 2594696 Sep  9 12:49 grubx64.efi
-rwx------ 1 root root  860824 Sep  9 12:49 mmx64.efi
-rwx------ 1 root root  960472 Sep  9 12:49 shimx64.efi
```

BOOTX64.CSV shows

```
shimx64.efi,ubuntu,,This is the boot entry for ubuntu
```

grub.csv shows:

```
    search.fs_uuid 5f783440-ebdd-4ad9-a536-999816acdde0 root hd0,gpt5 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

Output of efibootmgr:

```
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,2001,0000,2002,2003
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001* USB HDD: OCZ     DIESEL
Boot0002* Unknown Device: 
Boot0004* ubuntu
Boot2001* EFI USB Device
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM
Boot2003* EFI Network
```

Comment: Disable Windows Fast Boot, shutdown your system and start it again.

Comment: @paladin, I mentioned in the post that I tried that.  Specifically, I disabled fast boot, SuperGrub to boot Mint, install grub, update grub, reboot and it boots right into Win 10.

Comment: Check UEFI settings > Boot menu (instead of the one time boot menu / boot override) and select Mint there. If there isn't a proper EFI entry to be selected you may have wrongly installed Linux in Legacy mode. Also of note is your ill-formed question title. If you think or expect Grub to be installed OVER any other bootloader then clearly you don't understand UEFI mode - all bootloaders co-exist in the ESP (EFI System Partition) and can be selected at any time - and that, your misunderstanding,  is where probably your problem starts.

Comment: @ChanganAuto When I enter the BIOS, I don't see any option to boot Linux Mint or Ubuntu.  You are correct about the title and I did reflect a misunderstanding.  I was thinking that both EFI and legacy use the MBR.  However, only EFI relies on a separate partition allowing for multiple bootloaders as you mentioned.  A Youtube video cleared that up, but I'm still stumped as to what is going wrong.

Comment: You have UEFI, noy BIOS, and there you should find a "Boot" menu where the "OS Selection" is chosen. Terminology may vary, check you user's manual. You can also manage the boot order from inside either OS (e.g. using the third-party EasyUEFI software in Windows or `efibootmgr` in Linux).

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks, I updated the title.  I also added the output of efibootmgr and it appears to have the correct order.  Although I don't think Unknown Device Boot0002 should be in the entry list.

Comment: Indeed 0004: Ubuntu should boot correctly. If itr doesn't then it means you have one of those rare laptops (or even rarer desktops) that'll boot Windows when in dual-boot no matter what.

Comment: What does `blkid /dev/sda5` and `efibootmgr -v` return?

Comment: About fdisk error: https://superuser.com/a/1410949 try (as root) `parted -l /dev/sda`

Comment: Since `efibootmgr -v` output seems to have more information then needed nowadays on some systems, please grep the output instead: `efibootmgr -v | grep ^Boot`

Comment: @Vilinkameni, thanks.  I was fixing the computer for my dad.  He'll be out of town for the next two weeks, but I will respond once I have access to the computer again.  Thanks.